# how to color waypoints or the directions polyline in v3 google map direction service

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using gmap v3 direction service. I am using waypoints. I am displaying three routes and i want all the three routes  to be in different color. how to change the color of the routes?

Answer (score 0):

All the routes are using PolyLines, and you can set the color by passing them a http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#PolylineOptions

The only problem is that each DirectionRenderer can only have one type of PolyLines, so you need to have more than one DirectionRenderer as far as I can understand, and I am not sure how they will work together if you try to display them on the same map.

Comment: i have to experiment and will get back.

Comment: @JayapalChandran did you figure it out?